# Data augmentation using Keras

Tags: python, image-processing, machine-learning, neural-network, keras

I am using CNN for image training, before that I am performing data augmentation on training dataset using keras.

I have some questions regarding the data augmentation:

1. Does the transform depend on the epoch specified in `fit_generator()`?
2. Is there any maximum number of epochs for fetching the augmented images?
3. Is there any best number of epoch, which can give all the possible output augmented data?
4. Whether the transform applied on the images are in sequence or random.
5. Does the output images will be repeated after some specified number of epochs? If yes, then what is that figure, if no, then what is the best figure to use? For example, suppose I have a image that I am passing with the rotation_range as 20. Then, I know that initially random rotation will be applied on the image within the rotation_range and the two consequent images will not be same. but I want to know whether there is any pattern of angles that will be applied on images. And whether the same pattern will be repeated after some number of iterations?

I am using

```
for images_iter, labels_iter in datagen.flow(image_dataset, Labels, batch_size=len(image_dataset), shuffle=False):
```

for taking the augmented data.

Where, **image_dataset** is image dataset of **shape [1, 28, 28, 1]**, **Labels** is just **0**.

Comment: First, where do you generate your generated set? Before training? During it?

Comment: Before training.

Comment: The question is a bit too broad and some of the points are not strictly python/keras related

Comment: Yeah, but I know fit_generator() is used during training.

Comment: @gionni, what points are talking about? If it is really like this, then it's definitely related to the data augmentation or machine learning.

Answer (score 2):

Answering your questions, one by one:

1. Nope, the transform is calculated only once, when you generate the set. As you say, you do before training, so that's all.
2. No, there's no such thing as 'max number of epochs for fetch the augmented images'.
3. That will depend on your network topology, and the task you want to accomplish.
4. This should be in sequence, but you can shuffle your set anytime you want.

EDIT:

5. *After that example*: No, there's no a number of images generated. The generator will lopp infinitely until you stop it.

See: https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/

Comment: I try to give example. Suppose I have a image and I am passing rotation_range as 20. In this case, is there any fixed number of output images which will be rotated by different angle?

Comment: 'Nope, the transform is calculated only once, when you generate the set. Ass you say, yo do before training, so that's all.'
But if, I will iterate it again and again before training, then it will generate different transform, e.g. rotation.

Comment: Have you tried to loop with the generator to generate n images, and then use them in you training?

Comment: Yes, I tried with flow() like 

`for images_iter, labels_iter in datagen.flow(image_dataset, Labels, batch_size=len(image_dataset), shuffle=False):`

Comment: Could you post that piece of code in your answer? So everyone can see it.